# Error building a request and initializing client for OkHttp3 on Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, okhttp

New to OkHttp, however I was able to track the following errors:

```
        val url = "https://api.letsbuildthatapp.com/youtube/home_feed"
        try {
            val request = Request.Builder().url(url).build()
        } catch(err: Error){
            println("Request Error: $err")
        }
```

This generates: "Request Error: java.lang.BootstrapMethodError: Exception from call site #5 bootstrap method"

```
        try {
            OkHttpClient()
        } catch(err: Error){
            println("Client Error: $err")
        }
```

This returns an error "Client Error: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: okhttp3.internal.Util"

Any help with these will be greatly appreciated.  TIA

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have an issue with the dependency and/or JVM. The `java.lang.BootstrapMethodError` may mean there is something work with the Java Runtime Environment. Please consider upgrading Java to the stable version (e.g. 11 or 1.8)

The `NoClassDefFound` error means you miss some classes from the OkHttp library in your project. There are likely to be several transitive dependencies from the .jar that you have in your project. Probably Gradle or Maven project will help to have all dependencies resolved correctly.